# Python PyQt4 ImportError when using Homebrew and Virtualenv in OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

`PyQt4` is installed on a OSX system using `homebrew` and using python 2.7.5. Virtualenvwrapper is used to setup an environment for the current project.

Running a python script that imports the `PyQt4` module gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui
```

`brew test pyqt` popups a PyQt window and the test appears to pass.

```
$ brew install PyQt
Warning: pyqt-4.10.4 already installed
```

**Question:** Why does the `ImportError` still occurs?

---

**Attempt 1**

Copied the `pyqt` directory from brew's install directory to virtualenv's `lib/python-2.7/site-packages` directory. Still getting the same error

```
File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui
```

---

**Attempt 2**

```
$ virtualenv test

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.10.1
```

To fix this error, we do:

```
$ easy_install --upgrade pip
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages test
```

Lets install a required package:

```
$ pip install pyserial
```

And we get the same error when we run the script that imports `pyqt`:

```
$ python test.py

File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui
```

Furthermore, `virtualenv` now appears broken in this virtualenv, but works in other virtualenvs:

```
$ virtualenv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.10.1
```

Comment: Depending on your version of `virtualenv`, the default may be to use `--no-site-packages`, in which case you shouldn't see a system installed package.

Comment: @juanchopanza Is it done simply by removing the file `no-global-site-packages.txt` in the `bin` directory? Did this and the same `ImportError` error still occurs.

Comment: You would have to try instantiating a new `virtualenv` with the `--system-site-packages` option. I'm not sure how to do that with `virtualenvwrapper`. For some very tedious reasons I haven't used it for a while.

Comment: @juanchopanza I tried your suggestion in the updated question under `Attempt 2` but met the same problem again, any ideas?